# disqus: comments that've been liked the most rise to the top...like youtube?

Tags: disqus

With Disqus, can I allow the most 'liked' or 'favorited' comments to rise to the top, sort of like YouTube? If not, are there any other commenting systems that have this functionality built in?

Comment: Is this a WordPress question? Have a look at the Disqus docs for the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other plugins to do this too. Here are some I can think off:

- [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/)
- [Comment Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/)
- [Comments Vote](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/commentsvote/)

I would suggest you use [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/) by Automattic which means it will always be up-to-date and most compatible with your site.